# How to retrieve CATIA Part object with com4j for java

Tags: java, jacob, com4j, catia

I’ve tried to use com4j to get the PartDocument of a Catia file but when I get the object it was a Document object and not a PartDocument object. By consequent I cannot access to the method “part” of my object. I try to cast Document to PartDocument but the system reaches a cast exception.
I ve tried with java 7 x86 or 64 and end up with the same results.

1. I generate the java code with

`java -jar tlbimp.jar -o E:\testcatia\src -p catia InfTypeLib.tlb`

`java -jar tlbimp.jar -o E:\testcatia\src -p catia SMTypeLib.tlb`

`java -jar tlbimp.jar -o E:\testcatia\src -p catia PartTypeLib.tlb`

`java -jar tlbimp.jar -o E:\testcatia\src -p catia CATIAAppTypeLib.tlb`

com4j has  built classes and we have : Document and PartDocument (PartDocument extends Document)

1. my program code

   `Application   app = COM4J.createInstance( catia.Application.class, "CATIA.Application" );
    Documents docs=app.documents();
    PartDocument partdoc = (PartDocument) docs.open(new Holder<>("E:\\test.CATPart"));
    Part part= partdoc.part();`

exception : com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9 cannot be cast to catia.PartDocument

Has anyone faced this kind of issue before, and if so I would be very thankful for a solution.

I have tried the JACOB API and it is working. The Document has a correct instance of a PartDocument but the code is too difficult to manipulate

```
`ActiveXComponent app =new ActiveXComponent("CATIA.Application");
app.setProperty("Visible", new Variant(true));
Dispatch oDocuments = app.getProperty("Documents").toDispatch();
Dispatch oDocument = Dispatch.call(oDocuments, "Open", "E:\\test.CATPart").toDispatch();
Dispatch oPart = Dispatch.get(oDocument,"Part").toDispatch();
Dispatch oBody = Dispatch.get(oPart,"MainBody").toDispatch();`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use QueryInterface (https://com4j.java.net/runtime-semantics.html)

```
Document doc = docs.open(new Holder<>("E:\\test.CATPart"));    
PartDocument part = doc.queryInterface( PartDocument.class);
```